# Debian: Updating package with PPA fails with error "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found"

Tags: debian, package-management, ppa, audacious

My operating system is Debian 9.1 with Cinnamon 3.2.7. I installed Audacious (version 3.7.2) from the Package Manager and want to update to the latest released. Per [these instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/08/audacious-39-released-with-qt-user.html), I attempted to update by entering the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8   
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install audacious
```

After a prompt to press Enter, I received the following output:

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpseyl6p36/pubring.gpg' created  
gpg: /tmp/tmpseyl6p36/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created  
gpg: key 531EE72F4C9D234C: public key "Launchpad webupd8" imported  
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found  
gpg: Total number processed: 1  
gpg:               imported: 1  
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.  
Exception in thread Thread-1:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner  
    self.run()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run  
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func  
    func(**kwargs)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key  
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key  
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup  
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree  
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd  
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd  
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)  
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.browser'
```

Then, when I attempted to run the update step (`sudo apt-get install
--only-upgrade audacious`), I received more errors:

```
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease  
Ign:2 http://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 InRelease                         
Ign:3 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                          
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                               
Hit:5 http://www.scootersoftware.com bcompare4 Release                           
Hit:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease       
Hit:8 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch Release                            
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexanderk23/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease         
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu disco InRelease     
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexanderk23/ppa/ubuntu artful Release  
  404  Not Found  
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu disco Release  
  404  Not Found  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexanderk23/ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Finally, when I ran the install step (`sudo apt install audacious`), it said the latest was already installed. It must not have accepted the PPA.

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
audacious is already the newest version (3.7.2-1+b1).  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 241 not upgraded.
```

After browsing online, I entered the following commands to undo my changes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt-key del 531EE72F4C9D234C  
sudo apt update
```

What additional commands do I need to run in order to get the PPA to add properly?

Comment: That PPA is for Ubuntu and Mint. Mixing repos from different distros is going to lead to all sorts of problems as you have found out. You could however install it from source or accept that when you use Debian you will be using older versions of software.

Comment: Thank you for the information, kemotep. Is it relatively straightforward to install programs from the source? I work as a software engineer, so I am probably capable of doing it, but I have not installed programs from source on Linux.

Comment: Installing from source can be non trivial as the software in question can depend on various libraries or other components that Debian does not have or does not have the right version of. [Here is more information on installing Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/download). I would recommend you keep it to a minimum what you install from source and try to manage everything with apt.

Comment: They admit in that link that their instructions for installing from source are not very useful. I gave it a try anyway, but I already ran into a problem with a dependency. That's too bad. I may try a little longer, but failing that, looks like I'm looking at either installing a different Linux distro or finding a new music player application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn’t answer your question as stated, but it will give you a packaged version of Audacious 3.10 on Debian 9. Here’s how to rebuild the current Buster package on Debian 9:

- enable Stretch backports, which we’ll need

  ```
  echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
  sudo apt update
  ```
- install some useful tools we’ll need

  ```
  sudo apt install devscripts
  ```
- switch to a temporary directory

  ```
  cd /tmp
  ```
- download the source packages

  ```
  dget -xu http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/audacious/audacious_3.10-1.dsc
  dget -xu http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/audacious-plugins/audacious-plugins_3.10-1.dsc
  ```
- start building Audacious

  ```
  cd audacious-3.10
  ```
- build a meta-package with the build-dependencies (this will allow us to clean up later)

  ```
  mk-build-deps debian/control
  ```
- install it then move it out of the way

  ```
  sudo apt install ./audacious-build-deps_3.10-1_all.deb
  mv audacious-build-deps_3.10-1_all.deb ..
  ```
- now build Audacious

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```
- install packages we’ll need to build the Audacious plugins (we can’t install Audacious on its own without those)

  ```
  cd ..
  sudo dpkg -i audacious-dev_3.10-1_amd64.deb libaudcore5_3.10-1_amd64.deb libaudgui5_3.10-1_amd64.deb libaudtag3_3.10-1_amd64.deb
  ```
- same process to build the plugins (with an upgrade of `debhelper` to the Stretch backports version, required here)

  ```
  cd audacious-plugins-3.10
  mk-build-deps debian/control
  sudo apt install -t stretch-backports debhelper
  sudo apt install ./audacious-plugins-build-deps_3.10-1_amd64.deb
  mv audacious-plugins-build-deps_3.10-1_amd64.deb ..
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```

The build is complicated by the inter-dependencies between Audacious and its plugins, which is why you need to build Audacious first, the install its libraries and development package, then build the plugins. Once all that’s done you can install Audacious itself using the resulting package:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i audacious_3.10-1_amd64.deb audacious-plugins_3.10-1_amd64.deb audacious-plugins-data_3.10-1_all.deb
```

To clean up the packages using during the build:

```
sudo apt purge audacious-dev build-essential debhelper devscripts gcc gcc-6 audacious-build-deps audacious-plugins-build-deps
sudo apt --purge autoremove
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use Ubuntu PPAs in Debian.

> Don't make a FrankenDebian
>   Debian Stable should not be combined with other releases. If you're trying to install software that isn't available in the current Debian Stable release, it's not a good idea to add repositories for other Debian releases. The problems might not happen right away, but the next time you install updates.
>
> The reason things can break is because the software packaged for one Debian release is built to be compatible with the rest of the software for that release. For example, installing packages from buster on a stretch system could also install newer versions of core libraries including libc6. This results in a system that is not testing or stable but a broken mix of the two.
>
> Repositories that can create a FrankenDebian if used with Debian Stable:
>
> Debian testing release (currently buster)
>
> Debian unstable release (also known as sid)
>
> Ubuntu, Mint or other derivative repositories are not compatible with Debian!
>
> **Ubuntu PPAs**

Source https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

What was wrong with Audacious from Debian Repositories? https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=audacious

Comment: When I installed Audacious from the Synaptic Package Manager, the version installed is 3.7.2, which is not the latest. The latest released by the developers is 3.10. Even if I can't get the absolute latest, I would at least like version 3.9, which has some fixes that I would like. Is there I way I can get a newer version than what's in Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: Backport from Buster? https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Comment: Looks like there may not be a backport for Audacious for my OS. From your link above, there is a jessie-backport, but not a stretch-backport. I entered the commands from the link you just posted (i.e., added line to sources.list, then apt-get -t stretch-backports install "audacious"), but it still says I already have the latest.

Comment: @DanielCharles you need to use stretch backports. It is just `stretch-backports` you are not using jessie. A lot of Debian information is "out of date" in the sense that the names are wrong but the task is the same.

Comment: I did not use jessie. I added ``deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main`` to /etc/sources.list and then entered ``apt-get -t stretch-backports install "audacious"``. Was this incorrect? The only reason I mentioned jessie it is that arochester's original link (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=audacious) only contains results for jessie-backport; there are no stretch-backports listed.

Comment: @DanielCharles its in Buster so you could use apt-pinning but it would be easier just to use the version stable provides or install a different distro that supports the version that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I don't want to use the version provided by Debian stable. There have been 5 new releases by the developers since then which contain fixes and improvements. I understand Debian is intentionally slow to adopt updates, for the sake of stability. I may switch back to Mint.